# Pebble SDK with Ionic or similar cross platform environment

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, cross-platform, pebble-sdk

is it possible to develop cross platform apps with ionic (2) or similar cross platform frameworks for the pebble watch with the pebble sdk?

The SDK is available for native android / iOS, so a possible way is to use that SDK library. But how should I realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic/Cordova cannot run native SDK's as they're still ultimately written in Objective-C/Swift for iOS and Java for Android.

Ionic/Cordova does not run any of your application using native code (ie. your code does not become Obj-C, Swift or Java, it stays as Javascript). It runs your app within a WebView as a Website. So really its not possible unless they offer an SDK for Javascript or someone has written a Cordova plugin for it.

If you're open to using a different Mobile Cross Platform Framework, React-Native will support custom Native Modules. Essentially, you can write your own Native Code that will be available to your Javascript.

- [iOS Native Modules in React-Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)
- [Android Native Modules in React-Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)